# Is it undefined behavior to static_cast down a type that isn't actually the type of the object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-cast

Here is an [discussion on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used/332086#332086) of the four kinds of explicitly cast.  But I've come across a question in the most-voted answer.

Quoted from the most-voted wiki answer:

> `static_cast` can also cast through inheritance hierarchies. It is unnecessary when casting upwards (towards a base class), but when casting downwards it can be used as long as it doesn't cast through  `virtual` inheritance. It does not do checking, however, and **it is undefined behavior to `static_cast` down a hierarchy to a type that isn't actually the type of the object**.

But in [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast),I read something less severely:
`static_cast < new_type > ( expression )`

> If new_type is a pointer or reference to some class D and the type of expression is a pointer or reference to its non-virtual base B, `static_cast` performs a downcast. This downcast is ill-formed if B is ambiguous, inaccessible, or virtual base (or a base of a virtual base) of D. Such `static_cast` **makes no runtime checks** to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D, and **may only be used safely** if this precondition is guaranteed by other means.

So in cppref it does not says **undefined behavior**,but instead less severely as **not safe** .

So when I do something like:

```
class A{virtual foo(){}};
class B:public A{};
class C:public B{};
int main()
{
  C*pc=new C;
  A*pa=static_cast<A*>(pc);//Ok,upcast.
  B*pb=static_cast<B*>(pa);//downcast,**is it undefined or just not safe?**
  C* pc1=static_cast<C*>(pb);//downcast back to C;
}
```

One more question,if it's not UB,is it UB to dereference `pb` ?

Comment: In the code you show, all casts are valid downcasts.

Comment: It *is* a perfectly valid defined behaviour, albeit useless. Because dereferencing that pointer will be an UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But what I quoted said it's UB,does I get something wrong or the quoted paragraph is not true?

Comment: @GreenScape Do you mean that dereferencing `pb` is UB?So it is valid until I dereference the pointer `pb` ?

Comment: `B` is a non-virtual base of `C`. So it can be seen as an *upcast* from `pc` to `pb`. At least I think so. If you want an authoritative answer you should add the `language-lawyer` tag and wait for an answer with a quote from the standard.

Comment: @bigxiao, exactly. Pointer type is just another built-in N-byte *kind of integer* type. You can use it just to store arbitrary data. Its perfectly valid to do so. But as cppref mentioned, to actually be able to use it (dereference) you have to guaranteed that pointer points to a valid and correct object.

Comment: @GreenScape But `pc`, `pa`, `pb` and `pc1` are all pointing to a valid object of type `C` (which is a `B` which is an `A`), so why should it be UB to dereference any pointer?

Comment: @bigxiao You are reading too much into the choice of words on cppref. "Not safe" is not formal, unlike UB.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, all examples of OP are perfectly valid and not an UB. I was talking generally. Sorry for conusion.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've thought the cppref is authoritive ,formal and strict on its description,since most of its content is quoted from the standard.

Comment: @bigxiao - Cppref is the best reference for C++ on the web. But it's not the standard, nor is it subject to the same required rigor. It's also much easier to fix if it contains a problematic wording.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cppreference is written in English with the intent to convey good understanding, it's not actually specification. But I have no problem with its wording here:

> Such `static_cast` makes no runtime checks to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D, and may only be used safely if this precondition is guaranteed by other means.

If you guarantee the precondition, it's fine. If you don't guarantee the precondition, then your code isn't safe. What does it mean for code to not be safe? Its behavior isn't defined.

The actual specification uses [this wording](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#11):

> If the prvalue of type “pointer to *cv<sub>1</sub>* `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

---

Either way, in your example, all of your casts are valid.

```
B*pb=static_cast<B*>(pa);//downcast,**is it undefined or just not safe?**
```

You're missing the condition. A downcast isn't undefined behavior, in of itself. It's only undefined behavior if there isn't actually an object of derived type there. And in this case `pa` is pointing to a `C`, which is a `B`, so the cast to a `B` is safe.

This, however, is not:

```
struct B { };
struct D1 : B { };
struct D2 : B { };

B* p = new D1;
static_cast<D2*>(p); // undefined behavior, no D2 object here
```

Comment: the `B* p = new D1;` may  not be compiled.They are not in the same hierarchy

Comment: @bigxiao Yeah that was a typo.

Comment: Did you mean [this paragraph](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#11)?

Comment: @PasserBy Yes I did! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's well defined behavior.

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`,” where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
>   to *cv2* `D`,” where `D` is a class derived (Clause 10) from `B`, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to `D`”
>   to “pointer to `B`” exists (4.10), *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and
>   `B` is neither a virtual base class of `D` nor a base class of a virtual base class of `D`. The null pointer value (4.10)
>   is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. **If the prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`” points
>   to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object
>   of type `D`**. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

(C++14 [expr.static.cast] (§5.9) ¶11, emphasis added)

`pa` points to an object of type `A` which is actually a subobject of a `B`, so the second cast is fine and the result points to a valid `B`. Your third cast is OK for the same reason  (`pb` points to a `B` subobject of a `C`).

The "not safe" bit expressed by cppreference is about the fact that there are no safety nets here: you have to know by your own means if the actual dynamic type of the pointed object is compatible with the cast you ask for; if you get it wrong there's no `std::bad_cast` or `nullptr` - you get bad old undefined behavior.